Drill hole external wall for security camera install
Have successfully drilled holes in inside of the home. Wanted to install security camera on outside wall. Finding it difficult to drill hold, even starting the hole is difficult. I understand if I am in the middle of drilling hole, I might have hit metal. Tried with speed 2 and high clutch setting and drill setting. It just made a small dent after drilling for few mins. From outside appearance, it does not look like brick, but I might be wrong as there may be a coating. Can someone tell me if I am doing anything wrong? Drill used is DeWalt and bit is cobalt
I am going only mount the camera and use the outside power outlet. So intended hole is not going to come from inside to outside. Just drilling for mounting the camera


Try a masonry drill bit.  Might also need a hammer drill or better.

Is it quite normal to have inside of walls as a drywall and outside wall masonry?

It is quite normal to have inside of walls as drywall and outside wall anything.  It would be rare for the inside wall to be masonry even if the outside wall is.  They'll almost always cover it up with something.  I've seen masonry internal walls, but they're usually decorative surfaces.  In a basement or garage, you might have masonry internal/external, but in living spaces, you will generally have drywall or similar.

Very likely the coating is over some form of brick or concrete or cinder block. Meaning: hammer drill.

Thanks for the reply. I am going only mount the camera and use the outside power outlet. So intended hole is not going to come from inside to outside. Just going for mounting  the camera

Ring camera and wifi
